# Impossible to match a digit with a REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I try to extract the '930' from 'EM 930' with following Regexp

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(info,'^[:space:]*[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]*[:space:]*([0-9]+)[:space:]*$','\1')
```

But it returns me the original string.
An idea why ?

---

Subsidiary question:
Why does the "\1" returned the original string when the pattern is not matched ? I expected it to return NULL, as in my other regexp experiences (eg Perl).

Who I can re-write this in a performant way so that I get of wel the matched string of well NULL ?

Comment: Do you want to explain why you typed the alphabet instead of using `[A-Z]`?

Comment: `(\d+)` doesn't this solve your question ?

Comment: regexp_substr might be better for extracting.  i.e. select numbers at the end of the string: select regexp_substr('EM 930', '\d*$') from dual;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your space character class was not exactly correct. If we change `[:space:]` to `[[:space:]]`, your regexp_replace works as you expect:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(info, '^[[:space:]]*[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]*[[:space:]]*([0-9]+)[[:space:]]*$','\1')
```

For the sake of succinctness, we could use the upper character class, `[[:upper:]]`, for `[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]`. This changes the function invocation to:

```
regexp_replace(info, '^[[:space:]]*[[:upper:]]*[[:space:]]*([0-9]+)[[:space:]]*$','\1')
```

Or escape characters could be used in lieu of character classes:

`\s` space

`\w` word character

`\d` digit character

```
regexp_replace(info, '^\s*\w*\s*(\d+)\s*$','\1')
```

Explanation:

Since your malformed character class, `[:space:]`, does not match the space that exists between 'EM' and '930', your search by parameter does not match any characters in the source parameter.

Your search by parameter,  `'^[[:space:]]*[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]*[[:space:]]*([0-9]+)[[:space:]]*$'`, is anchored to the beginning and end of the column, info, thus it can only match the column, info, one time at most.

In your case, there is no match and the character group, `'\1'` which is associated with `'([0-9]*)'`, has no value.

Consequently, no characters are replaced and you are left with original value of the column, info, `'EM 930'`.

interesting variations to better understand this function:

-If your corrected function invocation had no pattern_to_replace_by parameter, `'\1'`, then a NULL would be returned:

regexp_replace(info, '^\s*\w*\s*(\d+)\s*$' ) FROM dual;

-Since you have a pattern_to_replace_by parameter, `'\1'`, and now it has the matching character group, the repeating digit group is returned:

930

Comment: I'm not in front my Oracle console anymore. That's for next week. However a test on my home's Mysql worked fine.